# Website nomenclature SEO practice involving name and surname

Tags: seo

What's better personal website nomenclature as per SEO?

1. [name]-[surname]  => dash in between
2. [name][surname] => void in between
3. [name].[surname] => dot in between.
4. something else?

Comment: What for? domain name? URL?

Comment: Good point ;)..

Comment: no!.. just for a general knowledge.. and if in future i go for a personal website with my own name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always best practice to try and make the domain as small as possible as people are more likely to remember domains without hyphens and dots. So in order the choices should be something like:

1. `NameSurname.com` (Best Choice).
2. `NameSurname.TLD` (Same but a different TLD type if available)
3. `Name-Surname.com` (If Best Choice is Taken.. hyphens are treated as word separators).
4. Personally I would avoid using dot in the domain name all together as its unnecessary unless you want a certain TLD type and all are taken.

Comment: I guess this might depend on language/country, too. E.g. I’d say in Germany it’s more common to use the hyphen und you rarely see concatenatedwordswithouthyphens (same for names) in domains.